# Where do I go to find out all Alert Me?

Tags: alert, task-list

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Where do I go to find out all the Alert Me commands I have for my email?

Can I add any other emails to the Alert Me function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I order to do this I either go to Home or the site collection where I created the Alerts, select Page, to go Alert Me and select Manage Alerts. There I will see all of the Alerts I have for my email. I can select the Alerts I want to delete and then delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Outlook to view, edit, delete all your SharePoint alerts:
https://abmlqsupport.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/386828-use-outlook-to-manage-all-your-portal-alerts